# Postgresql логирование

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, логирование

Мне нужно сделать полное логирование sql запросов в самом постгресе; запустить pg_dump; и тогда все действия pg_dump-а будут в нем (все sql запросы). Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы логировать все выполняемые запросы необходимо в конфигурации базы сделать

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
```

либо

```
log_statement = 'all'
```

`log_min_duration_statement` будет писать время выполнения запросов помимо самих запросов.

Обе настройки можно выставлять не только глобально в `postgresql.conf`. но и точечно на отдельные базы либо пользователей.